# linking to a the pdf folder within my wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to link to a a pdf which is inside the pdf folder of my child theme, at the moment I'm using the following php

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/child-theme/pdf/bar.pdf' ) ); ?>
```

and was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this that doesnt involve including wp-content/themes ?

Comment: why not directly `/wp-content/themes/child-theme/pdf/bar.pdf` ?

Comment: Do you just want the link to point to a PDF directory outside of the WP folders?

Comment: @paul yeah that would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to reach your child theme is through `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/pdf/bar.pdf'; ?>
```

You can find more information in the Codex: [get stylesheet directory uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new directory in your root called `pdf`

```
echo '<a href="/pdf/doc.pdf">Anchor Text</a>';
```

However, I'm not sure what real benefit this will provide.